# PHP5 cgi 500 error End of script output before headers

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I set up an Ubuntu server 14.04 with LAMP and I've changed the Apache document root to `/srv/myserver/` instead of `/var/www/`

So far so good and html scripts run ok but when I try to run a PHP script I get a 500 error (Internal Server Error) 
This is what the error log says:

`End of script output before headers: phpinfo.php, referer: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/web/html/`

I have PHP5 cgi installed and I just can't figure out where that error comes from.

Can anyone helps me ?

Thanks for advance